# Is there a way to increase the amount of users which can register per hour for Firebase Authentication permanently?

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

Screenshot of the limit specified:

[image: Screenshot]

This is the [link](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/limits) to the documentation for the image above.

Screenshot of increasing quota:

[image]

I am aware that we can temporary increase the quota in the console as shown above but that is temporary.

Let's say that your app becomes big and the signup rate is high. Then wouldn't it be bad for business if they can't signup suddenly. Or is that the plan which is once your app becomes big, you have to contact them and ask for a custom quote?

Answer (score 0):

You might be misunderstanding the limit.  It's not "100 per hour".  It's "100 per hour **per IP address**".  It's extremely unlikely that all your new users will be coming from the same IP, and still pretty unlikely that it will exceed 100 per hour (unless somehow your app went viral - if you did that, congratuations! - you will certainly make lots of money).  If you have a global user base all trying to sign up at the same time, then they will each be coming from a different IP address, and the limit will not be exceeded at all.

If your app is very special in this way, and your really need to increase this limit, then you should [reach out to Firebase support directly](https://support.google.com/firebase/contact/support) to explain why you need to exceed this limit.

Comment: I see. Thank you for your clarification. I did misunderstand the limit part.